# Fetching external files from URL with custom Microsoft Teams App

Tags: bots, webhooks, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Im currently making a custom app for Microsoft Teams, and im trying to get it to fetch files from a URL without One-drive and Sharepoint. I've been reading the documentation on bots and outgoing webhooks, but they seem to all utilize either one-drive or sharepoint. I want my custom app to fetch files from a URL and then upload them to the corresponding Team or Channel within MS Teams.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: this should be possible, there are Graph APIs to upload to Teams Drives ( which are actually backed by SharePoint and OndeDrive ) . One thing to pay attention to is that you may need to explicitly add the urls for your webapp or source location to your application manifest `    "validDomains": [  "your.app.net" ]`

Comment: Also note that you have not actually asked a question, but only stated a very broad problem that you want to solve.
I suggest you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some inspiration

Comment: @JosVerlinde Thx for you answer. Ive taken a look at the graph APIs but it looks like my files have to already be on a MS related application, as in, either on sharepoint or onedrive. My goal is to fetch a list of files from a URL (so files that are not on onedrive or sharepoint) and then upload those files to the onedrive related to the team im in when fetching. There are specific MS cards to visualize things within teams, but there is no card for file. The cards im talking about: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference

Comment: regarding Cards: Using Adaptive cards the source for the images or artwork for your notification can be anywhere that you have declared as a trusted domain in your teamsmanifest.
Sample: 
https://adaptivecards.io/samples/ImageGallery.html

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch the recent files using graph Api, could you please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-recent?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) document to fetch the recent files.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding Cards and sending notifications:**

Using [Adaptive Cards](https://adaptivecards.io) the source for the images or artwork for your notification can be anywhere that you have declared as a valid domain in your [Teams Manifest - validDomains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#validdomains)

Note that while ODB/SPO are the most common / natural locations for files in teams , there is nothing special about these locations or urls.   (clearly you need access and authentication, but these are not special, just essential)

Sample fetching artwork from non-SPO locations: https://adaptivecards.io/samples/ImageGallery.html

Adaptive Cards in teams : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/design-effective-cards?tabs=desktop